# SPARQL over HTTP

Tags: http, sparql, postman, apache-jena

I am trying to query my dataset via HTTP 'get' method. I am using POSTMAN to use the HTTP method. 
Here is my complete url
//localhost:3030/DS-1/sparql?query=PREFIX test:http://www.semanticweb.org/muhammad/ontologies/2017/2/untitled-ontology-14# SELECT ?KPIs ?Trends WHERE {?KPIs test:hasTrend ?Trends}
I am getting the error shown in the picture

P.s: i am using Apache jena fuseki server for my dataset. The same query work in fuseki.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hSRV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must percent-encode the query string for use over HTTP.  Here, the # is a problem.